# Changing the caption of Yes-No button in jqdialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can we change captions of Yes-No buttons in jqdialog box of jQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to JQuery UI Dialog, you can use the buttons option which takes an array defining the buttons you want to appear in the dialog:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
] });
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no way to override the labels at the moment, if you don't want or have time to implement the overriding feature you can just modify the non-minified version of the plugin.

https://github.com/knadh/jqdialog/blob/master/jqdialog.js

```
var t = null;
$.jqDialog = {
    escape_callback: null,
    enter_callback: null,

    //________button / control labels
    labels: {
        ok: 'Ok',
        yes: 'Yep',
        no: 'Nope',
        cancel: 'Cancel'
    },
```